# How to make this sliding window?

Tags: tables, strings

[image]

Book: [Handbook of Exact String Matching Algorithms](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220693416_Handbook_of_Exact_String_Matching_Algorithms)

**Update:**

```
% compiler: xelatex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2.5cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}

\newcommand{\hlcd}[2][black!30]{{%
    \colorlet{foo}{#1}%
    \sethlcolor{foo}\hl{#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\hlcl}[2][black!15]{{%
    \colorlet{foo}{#1}%
    \sethlcolor{foo}\hl{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}

\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}

$y$ 
\ttfamily
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
\hline
 G C A T C G C A G A G A G T \hlcd{A}  \hlcd{T} \hlcd{A} C A G T A C \hlcl{G} \\
 \hline
\end{tabular} \\

1 \\

$x$ 
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
\hline
G C A G A G A  \hlcd{G} \\
\hline
\end{tabular} \\


\end{document}
```

[image: update2]

This is what I can do so far. Tabulars are not aligned vertically.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Unfortunately, this is not a "please do this for me" site. If have a work in progress but you're stuck somewhere, post your code as a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output. Then explain what you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `nicematrix` and then use Ti*k*Z commands to draw the various annotations in the `CodeBefore` (to highlight individual cells) and `CodeAfter` (to box groups of cells).

Note that you will have to compile this 3 times for any changes that affect cell positions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{NiceTabular}{*{24}{@{\;}>{\ttfamily}c@{\;}}}
\CodeBefore [create-cell-nodes]
  \tikz{\foreach \c in {1-15, 1-16, 1-17, 1-24, 3-15, 5-16, 7-24, 9-24, 11-17}
    \node[fill=gray!50, inner xsep=4pt, inner ysep=6.5pt] at (\c) {} ; 
  }
\Body
G&C&A&T&C&G&C&A&G&A&G&A&G&T&A&T&A&C&A&G&T&A&C&G\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&1\\
&&&&&&&G&C&A&G&A&G&A&G\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&2\\
&&&&&&&&G&C&A&G&A&G&A&G\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&3\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&G&C&A&G&A&G&A&G\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&4\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&G&C&A&G&A&G&A&G\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&5\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&G&C&A&G&A&G&A&G\\
\CodeAfter
  \tikz{ 
    \node[draw, fit=(1-1)(1-24), label={left:$y$}]{};
    \node[draw, fit=(1-8)(1-15), inner ysep=5pt, inner xsep=1pt]{};
    \node[draw, fit=(3-8)(3-15), label={left:$x$}]{};
    \node[draw, fit=(5-9)(5-16), label={left:$x$}]{};
    \node[draw, fit=(7-17)(7-24), label={left:$x$}]{};
    \node[draw, fit=(9-17)(9-24), label={left:$x$}]{};
    \node[draw, fit=(11-17)(11-24), label={left:$x$}]{};
  } 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Can you help me with empty table cell that has custom width and custom notation? (The above Handbook, Figure 14.2, page 92)

Comment: @hungngt: I suggest you post a new question and link this one.